# DNS only seems to work with VPS provider's servers

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

On Ubuntu Server 15.04. My `/etc/resolv.conf` is the only place I can find DNS servers and it looks like this:

```
# Automatically generated by OnApp (2.3.1)
domain localdomain
nameserver [vps_provider_ip]
nameserver [vps_provider_ip_2]
```

DNS works fine when at least one of these IPs is present in the file. As soon as I remove them and insert `8.8.8.8` (or any other DNS server), the server can't ping google.com. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @davidbaumann Yes

Comment: That makes sense as the first line says `# Automatically generated by OnApp (2.3.1)`, so it is not behaving in the usual manner..you should use `OnApp` to change the DNS settings..

Comment: @heemayl I don't have OnApp or similar on my VPS control panel. I think OnApp might be used just in initial setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted my VPS provider and they told me all DNS servers except their own are blocked in order to provide better DDoS protection.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to install `unbound` package and replace `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` with `dns=unbound`. For my configuration it works now flawlessly.